# Batch - Parsing the output of Tracert

Tags: parsing, batch-file, awk, traceroute

i would like to ask for some help with the output of tracert in windows, ie i have this output :

```
Tracing route to Y.Y.Y.Y over a maximum of 30 hops

1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  X.X.X.X 
2   103 ms    71 ms    22 ms  X.X.X.X 
3    35 ms    51 ms    35 ms  X.X.X.X 
....
```

and i would like to produce a file that contains only the X.X.X.X or as an intermediate step to get there, only the lines of tracer that actually contain IPs. Ie :

```
X.X.X.X
X.X.X.X
X.X.X.X
```

I ve tried this through a batch file :

```
for /f "tokens=8" %%a in ('tracert -4 -d 8.8.8.8^|find "ms"') do (
    @echo %%a >D:\panagos\desktop\ips.txt
)
```

but instead of the desired output i get only :

```
Y.Y.Y.Y
```

I ve also tried calling on binaries from cygwin to do this, ie :

```
D:\path\to\slash\bin\awk '{ print $8 }' filein > fileout
```

but that doesnt work either. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `but that doesnt work either` what exactly is going wrong? on linux, I tried `awk '/ ms/ {print $8}' filein` which should give your expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following batch file:

**GetIPs.cmd:**

```
@echo off
rem skip 2 header lines
rem ip address is the 8th token
for /f "skip=2 tokens=8" %%d in ('tracert -4 -d 8.8.8.8') do (
  echo %%d
  )>>ips.txt
endlocal
```

**Example:**

```
F:\test>tracert -4 -d 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to 8.8.8.8 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.42.129
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    53 ms    48 ms    48 ms  10.248.29.129
  4    46 ms    48 ms    48 ms  10.247.82.25
  5    55 ms    48 ms    48 ms  10.247.82.6
  6    55 ms    48 ms    48 ms  10.247.82.9
  7    46 ms    48 ms    48 ms  10.247.82.18
  8    55 ms    48 ms    48 ms  87.237.20.236
  9    56 ms    59 ms    48 ms  87.237.20.85
 10    56 ms    58 ms    47 ms  74.125.52.216
 11    55 ms    48 ms    51 ms  216.239.41.179
 12    58 ms    48 ms    59 ms  216.239.57.83
 13    58 ms    59 ms    48 ms  8.8.8.8

Trace complete.

F:\test>GetIPs

F:\test>type ips.txt
192.168.42.129
10.248.29.129
10.247.82.25
10.247.82.6
10.247.82.9
10.247.82.18
87.237.20.236
87.237.20.85
74.125.52.216
216.239.41.179
216.239.57.83
8.8.8.8
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.

Answer (score 3):

Read [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

> ```
> command > filename        Redirect command output to a file
> command >> filename       APPEND into a file
> ```

Use either

```
type NUL >D:\panagos\desktop\ips.txt
for /f "tokens=8" %%a in ('tracert -4 -d 8.8.8.8^|find "ms"') do (
    @echo %%a >>D:\panagos\desktop\ips.txt
)
```

or (better)

```
@echo OFF
>D:\panagos\desktop\ips.txt (
    for /f "tokens=8" %%a in ('tracert -4 -d 8.8.8.8^|find "ms"') do (
        echo %%a
    )
)
```

Also note that your script hides *unreachable* hosts, see that 12th hop in next example has only 7 tokens:

```
==> tracert -d 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to 8.8.8.8 over a maximum of 30 hops

 …
 11    36 ms    44 ms    36 ms  108.170.234.149
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13    36 ms    36 ms    35 ms  8.8.8.8

Trace complete.
```