# Is there a way to change command-line output before saving to a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, traceroute

I'm writing a program that uses the "tracert" command to find traceroutes for IP addresses, which I'll then use to do some things with.

How I had planned to do this is, is by dumping the output for all IP addresses into a text file by appending with `>>output.txt` and then reading it in with Python or something and turn it into something usable.

My issue with this is that tracert also shows in its output some things that are of no use to me, such as the first line that says where it's tracing to and what the maximum number of hops is, or the last line that only says: "Trace complete".

The thing is that I'm going to be tracing 3500+ IP addresses, and that number is only going to grow, so that is a whole lot of text that I'm printing in a file that is absolutely useless.

That's why my question is: Is there any way that I can modify the output of the command before saving it, in a batch file?

The command I'm running:

```
tracert -h 30 -w 500 XX.XXX.XXX.XX >>cmd_output.txt
```

The output it gives:

```
Tracing route to XYZ.net 
[XX.XXX.XXX.XX]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    41 ms    18 ms     2 ms  text.net [XXX.XXX.XXX.X] 
  2     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  text.net [XX.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  text.net [XX.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
  4     5 ms     5 ms     5 ms  text.net [XXX.XX.XX.XXX] 
  5     5 ms     5 ms     5 ms  text.net [XXX.XX.XX.X] 
  6    25 ms    25 ms    25 ms  XYZ.net [XX.XXX.XXX.XX] 

Trace complete.
```

Comment: simplest way: `tracert www.google.com|find " ms ">>file.txt` or `tracert www.google.com||findstr /bc:" "` (print only lines that start with a space)

Comment: You've told us what you deem to be useless, but not what you actually want in your output. For my mind, I see no purpose in all of the columns either. Please let us know what you want whilst researching how to do it yourself because this isn't a coding request site.

Comment: The question is: __Is there any way that I can modify the output of the CMD before saving it in a batch file?__ And the answer is: __Yes, there are multiple ways to filter or reformat an application output before writing into a file.__ We would not need to write more, but [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) suggested already usage of __FINDSTR__. __FIND__ could be perhaps also used as filter application. It is also possible to use __FOR__, __SET__ and __IF__ to reformat the output before writing into a file. And there are a lot more methods. Run them with `/?` for help.

Comment: You should accept answer from @Stephan.  Thats what you want.

Comment: @JJF: difficult to accept a comment... This question is too broad to be answered. Aas Compo already noted, we need to know at least what kind of output is required.

Comment: Thanks guys, I try to be as clear as possible, but it's the first time I ask a question around here, thanks for being so kind. I really only need the number of the hop and the IP-adress associated with it. I'll do some research into the findstr method. Perhaps you could point me in a direction where I could find documentation for this kind of programming? I have probably not searched for the right things to get the documentation.

Comment: How should something like  `4     *        *        *   Request timed out.` be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following helps, I believe you can you use it and adjust it to your own use: [Batch - Parsing the output of Tracert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062553/batch-parsing-the-output-of-tracert)

Answer (score 0):

The exact formula to skip the N first lines from one command's output is:

```
for /f "skip=N tokens=*" %a in ('<command>') do @echo %a
```

In your case:

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=*" %a in ('tracert -h 30 -w 500 XX.XXX.XXX.XX ') do @echo %a >> cmd_output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your replies and some more searching, I have come up with this solution:

```
@echo off
rem token 1 is hop-number
rem token 6,7 or 8 may be IP, depending on whether 2 or less requests dont receive a response.
for /f "tokens=1,6,7,8 delims=* " %%a in ('tracert -d -h 30 -w 350 8.8.8.8^|findstr /bc:" " ') do (
  echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d
  )>>ips.txt
endlocal
```

This yields the following response:

```
1, <1, ms, 192.168.1.240
2, 1, ms, 195.114.237.65
3, 1, ms, 94.247.72.33
4, <1, ms, 82.150.154.129
5, 1, ms, 217.170.0.244
6, 2, ms, 193.239.117.142
7, 2, ms, 108.170.241.140
8, 2, ms, 216.239.41.49
9, 5, ms, 74.125.37.130
10, 209.85.243.253, , 
11, 5, ms, 108.170.237.135
12, , , 
13, 5, ms, 8.8.8.8
```

In each line, before the first comma is always the hop-number. Then the IP address may be after the first, second or third comma. Since tracert sends three requests per hop one, two or three of those requests can fail.

If a request fails, the result is "*", instead of "X ms" and because I'm delimiting with spaces, if I would always take the 8th token, it might not contain the IP address, or anything for that matter.

This code will always contain the IP address, but will still contain some superfluous data if fewer then two requests failed, because then token 6 and or 7 will contain some part of "X ms".

In the response, you'll see all requests were successful, except for hop 10, where two requests failed and hop 12, where three requests failed and thus tracert failed to return an IP address.

If anyone has any bright ideas on how to remove these last bits of superfluous data, it would be appreciated. Otherwise this is a perfectly workable output for me. So thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('tracert -d -h 30 -w 350 8.8.8.8 ^|findstr /bc:" "') do (
  for %%c in (%%b) do set ip=%%c
  set ip=!ip:[=!
  set ip=!ip:]=!
  echo !ip!|findstr "[0-9]" >nul || set "ip=-"
  echo %%a, !ip!
)
```

the second `for` (`%%c`) gets the very last word of the line (which is either an IP address or an IP address in brackets or the last word of "Request timed out." (`out.` in English Windows versions). The rest of the lines is just to beautify the result (removing brackets, replacing anything that has no number (is no IP address) with a `-`

Maybe you want to replace the two `echo ...` lines with just:

```
  echo !ip!|findstr "[0-9]" >nul && echo %%a, !ip!
```

This wouldn't output lines without an IP address.

For the `&&` and `||` thingy, see [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

For the `!variable!` syntax see [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)